# Connecting multiple data entities to the user object

Tags: users, entities

I need to create a simple order system in Drupal 7. This will be a site for a meat wholesaler so I don't need a webshop.
Users are able to register and fill in a webform to order products. However I'll need to handle different shipping addresses for the users, and let them choose a shipping address upon ordering.
What I have in mind is connecting the shipping addresses to the user object (billing address is already on the user form).

Which method is better?

1. Create a field collection entity for the shipping addresses and add it to the user form
2. Leave the user form alone and create a new content type that can be added/edited by users and use the UID to decide which address belongs to which user

I'd like to let users edit their shipping addresses anytime on their user page, preferably independently from the other datas.

If anyone done something like this before, please share some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably be best to create a Shipping Address content type. You should also look at the [Address Field](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield) module to collect the addresses rather than field collection.

Then you can create a simple view to list the shipping addresses (Node Tile not linked) using a contextual filter on uid. Then set up a node reference field in your webform using the view to provide the values. The user can then select which shipping address to use for his order.

On the user page you mav use the same view (separate display listing titles as edit links) to let them edit their shipping addresses, and give them a link to add new addresses if necessary.